# Insert DATE as DATE->Format() in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I' trying to insert a DATE into MySQL database. Date has been set as new DateTime() and formatted to "Y:m:d". A variable carries the new DateTime but when inserting it to a DATE field in MYSQL only ceros are inserted. The DATE field is not getting NULL results but just CEROS 000-00-00.
This is my code.

```
    $bigin=date("Y-m-d");
    $datetime_bigining = new DateTime($bigin);
    $datetime_bigining->modify('-60 day');
    $datetime_bigining->format('Y:m:d');

    $insert_days= mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tocreate (date_full)  VALUES".$datetime_bigining->format('Y-m-d').");") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$datetime_bigining->format('Y-m-d');` for MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be simplified tremendously (and fixed):

```
$datetime_beginning = new DateTime('60 days ago');
$insert_days= mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tocreate (date_full)  
    VALUES ('".$datetime_beginning->format('Y-m-d')."');") or die(mysql_error());
```

1. You can combine your first three lines of code
2. Your fourth line is unnecessary and useless
3. You have a couple of SQL syntax errors (missing parenthesis, missing quotes)

Comment: Was just typing pretty much this. +1

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I'm getting an error and the query dies on an error that I can't even understand using your suggestion on the MYSQL_QUERY side. The rest works fine with your suggestion.

Comment: I used you code including the first line but the error comes when I try to increment $datetime_beginning by one day like this $datetime_bigining->modify('+1 day'). The Query works with your code and I appreciate it but the query resides inside of a loop that increments this date by one day several times. At this point the error I'm getting is when I try to increment this day by one day. Any Help?

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what the error is and seeing the code. You might need to ask a new question showing all of that. If you do I'll do my best to help.

Comment: check your PHP version. the modify() thing won't work unless you have 5.3 or higher i believe. i had a similar date issue in a program i wrote recently

Comment: for PHP 5.2, try date_modify($datetime_beginning, "+1 day") rather than $datetime_beginning->modify("+1 day)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$datetime_bigining->format('Y-m-d');` This is the format that MySQL expects.

Comment: Also, it's beginning!